# WPF text flickering between cleartype and non-cleartype

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cleartype

I have a problem with WPF... it's kinda odd.

I recently migrated to using MahApps.Metro for my window and when I'm on my Login Screen it flickers between cleartype and non-cleartype every few seconds

[image: Example]

Here are my XAML files

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="LegendaryClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="LegendaryClient" Height="600" Width="1024" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="1024"
        ShowIconOnTitleBar="True" SaveWindowPosition="True" Icon="Icon.ico" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" TitleCaps="False">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
        <Controls:WindowCommands>
            <Button Content="settings" />
            <Button x:Name="ThemeButton" Click="ThemeButton_Click" Content="theme"/>
        </Controls:WindowCommands>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Steel.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Container" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

and

```
<Page x:Class="LegendaryClient.Windows.LoginPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="672" d:DesignWidth="1024"
    Title="LoginPage">
    <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0">
        <Image x:Name="LoginImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill" Panel.ZIndex="-2" />

        <Label x:Name="WelcomeLabel" Content="Login to League of Legends" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="25,0,0,290">
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="350" Margin="20,0,0,50">
            <Grid x:Name="LoginGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="LoginUsernameBox" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,40,0,0" FontSize="16"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="RememberUsernameCheckbox" Content="Remember Username" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,80,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" IsChecked="True"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Margin="10,90,0,0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="LoginPasswordBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,120,0,0" FontSize="16"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="RememberPasswordCheckbox" Content="Remember Password" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,160,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" />
                <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,180,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="41" Click="LoginButton_Click" IsDefault="True" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="RegionComboBox" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Regions}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="5"/>
            </Grid>
            <Controls:ProgressRing x:Name="LoggingInProgressRing" IsActive="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Label x:Name="LoggingInLabel" Content="Logging in..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </Grid.Effect>
        </Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="ErrorTextBox" Text="Error" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsReadOnly="True" Width="350" Height="20" FontSize="12" FontWeight="999" Foreground="#FFFF7373" Margin="25,0,0,15" Background="{x:Null}" Panel.ZIndex="-1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Visibility="Hidden">
            <TextBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
            </TextBox.Effect>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `<Controls:ProgressRing x:Name="LoggingInProgressRing" IsActive="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Visibility="Hidden"/>` was causing my text to flicker for some reason... Putting it outside the grid stopped the blurring